# Fulfilling removed cloud area with free cloud data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, landsat, masking, cloud-cover

I have completed doing cloud removal with Landsat image (in this case is Lansat 8) in the Google Earth Engine. Of course the result of this process is the cloud pixels become no data, consequently the area which was as the cloud is perforated.
I want to process this image to the nest step for classification and image transformation. So I want to fill the holey areas with no cloud data from other time period so that my study area has complete data within.

[image: The result of cloud removal]

How can I solve this problem as to fill the holey image?
I use this cloud masking scirpt:

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([97.90305, 3.98383]);

function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;

  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions. 
  var mask1 = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));

  var mask2 = image.select('B.*').gt(0).reduce('min');

  // Return the masked image, scaled to TOA reflectance, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask1.and(mask2)).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

//Clip
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(roi);
};

// Map the function over one year of data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
    .map(maskL8sr)
    .map(clipToCol);

var composite = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25]));

// Display the results.
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B7_p25', 'B6_p25', 'B4_p25'], min: 0, max: 0.2});
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example script may answer your question-

```
// Load a cloudy Landsat 8 image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20130603');
Map.addLayer(image,
         {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.5},
         'original image');

// Load another image to replace the cloudy pixels.
var replacement = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20130416');

// Compute a cloud score band.
var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');

// Set cloudy pixels to the other image.
var replaced = image.where(cloud.gt(10), replacement);

// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(image, 9);
Map.addLayer(replaced,
         {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.5},
         'clouds replaced');
```

using `where`you can fill the cloud mask patches.

Comment: Can you please explain what "gt(10) is" is?
Does this script work to replace no data (in case of cloud masking)?

Comment: Check this link- https://code.earthengine.google.com/1394e2b405f4137b62ad39de6a882e1f        .if I am correct cloud.gt(10) accounts for all the cloud cover present in an image.

Comment: Thank you. any question else, how do you select replacement image? do you d it manually or using machine to select?

Comment: by visual interpretation, replacement image was selected to fill the cloud removed locations.